# Action before startActivity()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm new in Android development and I've a problem when I create my new activity.

I want to use my activity before start it. For example, I have try it:

```
MyActivity menu = new MyActivity();
menu.setXmppreception(reception);
Intent intent = new Intent(Screen.this,MyActivity.class);
Screen.this.startActivity(intent);
```

But, my "menu" and "MyActivity.class" aren't the same instance. Consequently I have try it:

```
MyActivity menu = new MyActivity();
menu.setXmppreception(reception);
Intent intent = new Intent(Screen.this,menu);
Screen.this.startActivity(intent);
```

But it doesn't work...
Have you a solution for help me?

Thanks for help and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that like you want, if you are looking to pass data between an activity you must use Extras, and you can pass just Serializable items.

**First Context (can be Activity/Service etc)**

You have a few options:

1) Use the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) from the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

2) Create a new Bundle

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

3) Use the [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) shortcut method of the Intent

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
mIntent.putExtra(key, value);
```

**New Context (can be Activity/Service etc)**

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // this getter is just for example purpose, can differ
if (myIntent !=null && myIntent.getExtras()!=null)
     String value = myIntent.getExtras().getString(key);
}
```

***NOTE:*** Bundles have "get" and "put" methods for all the primitive types, Parcelables, and Serializables. I just used Strings for demonstrational purposes.

Comment: I think I'll use the third option (putExtra() method). If I understood everything I must implements "Serializable" in my XMPPReception class, isn't it?

Thanks again.

Comment: Probably yeah `reception` must be Serializable, but Eclipse will tell for you.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to create the new activity yourself, Android system does it for you. 
If you want to go from `Screen Activity` to `MyActivity`, you can do this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Screen.this,MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and then, in you `MyClass` java file, in the onCreate method, you could do :

```
this.setXmppreception(reception);
```

This way, I think you get you wanted, no?